# How to check if ActiveRecord inverse_of detection worked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

According to the [documentation for ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Bi-directional+associations), ActiveRecord can automatically determine if a `belongs_to` association of one module is the inverse of a `has_one` or `has_many` association of another model.

However, I want to make sure that this detection actually succeeds on some associations I am not sure about (for instance, I have an `belongs_to` which doesn't exactly match the other model's name, but has `class_name` set). Is there a way to check that the `inverse_of` detection was applied to a specific association? Ideally, I would add something to the project's test suite to ensure that the association is bi-directional as intended.

Comment: This isn't quite what you're asking, but you should set the ":inverse" option on the associations, rather than leaving Rails to try to calculate the inverse relationships automatically, if you want to leverage the `inverse` functionality somewhere.

Comment: @MaxWilliams No, you should not. It's a perfect case of convention over configuration. I believe writing superfluous code is not the rails way, i.e. it makes no sense to write an `inverse_of` option if Rails >= 4.1's automatic inversion detection mechanism already picks it up. Besides, for 99% of the cases I run into, it's not about the functionality but the performance boost, so no leverage, still advantage. The question is about it being difficult to figure out if an inverse has been detected at all.

Comment: I think it makes a lot of sense from a readability/self-documenting code point of view: if the option a) guarantees that Rails will do the right thing and b) makes it obvious to your colleagues that something unusual is happening then what's the harm?

Comment: This convention is arguably more complicated than most of the others, but I think explicitly specifying `inverse_of` at places where Rails already does it implicitly would confuse me, as it implies something out of the ordinary where it really isn't. For the exact same reason, you could e.g. also include a `table_name` in every model, `foreign_key` and `class_name` in associations where Rails automatically figures it out. The question then becomes: where to draw the line? I personally believe using Rails implies knowing the defaults, taking them for granted and be specific about the exceptions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start a rails console, and run:

```
> Rails.application.eager_load!

> ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each {|m| puts "=== #{m} ==="; m.reflect_on_all_associations.each {|a| puts "#{a.name} => #{a.has_inverse?}"}}
```

It will dump a list with all your models, their associations and if known their inverse, otherwise 'false', nil or an empty string (based on why it's unknown.)

Comment: Note this does not check if the inverse association is actually defined. You can do `a.inverse_of&.name` instead to only display the ones that are properly defined on the other model.

Comment: +1 @mckeed Great point! For clarity: it doesn't check if it is ***explicitly*** defined, which could be important, though for the purpose of making sure it's applied - to my best interpretation of OP's question, the original answer works. Reason I comment is that in light of convention over configuration we prefer to let Rails automatically do its thing where it can, but if your prefer to explicate it (which is fair IMO, this convention isn't exactly the most simple one), then yes, add the name to the output to help ensure it! 

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I'm talking about checking whether you defined the inverse association at all, not merely whether you explicitly set its inverse. In Rails 6.1 at least, if you haven't explicitly defined the association on the other model (as in missing the entire belongs_to or whatever line), your `Reflection#has_inverse?` test will pass but when you actually go to use the original association you'll get a `ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError`.

Comment: I should clarify my previous comment: it's only an issue when you have specified `inverse_of:` on the association, because in that case `has_inverse?` will just return that instead of actually checking if it exists. So I suppose for the question of checking that automatic inverse detection has worked, it's fine, but for testing your associations in general it could lead to false positives.